# Problema con Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, sintaxis

Tengo problemas con Visual Studio Code, cuan termino de escribir la sintaxis, estoy trabajando con react, me corre toda la sintaxis haciendo ilegible el código. Por ejemplo **" <
h2>{name} <
/h2>"** Me lo va dejando así, cuando le pongo guardar

Comment: Ve a tus preferencias (*File > Preferences > Settings* o `Ctrl + ,`) y en la sección *Text Editor > Formatting* desmarca la casilla *Format on Save*. Eso evitará que se autoformatee el código cada vez que guardas los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que extenciones tienes instaladas en VSCode, si no es nada de ello revisa las ultimas librerias adjuntas, sino reinicia tu VSCode y si el problema persiste reinstala la libreria de React...! Suerte en tu proyecto